# repository of test cases of hard, combinatorial, NP problems

Tags: algorithms

I'm sure there are standard test cases of hard, combinatorial, NP problems, ... (like knapsack, bin packing, partitioning, ...) that practitioners or algorithm developers use when they compare a new algorithm against existing ones (as I often see in papers), but where can I find them ? (a single repository is more preferable than many scattered)

Comment: [Complexity Zoo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo) and it's companions [Complexity Garden](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Garden) + [Complexity Dojo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Dojo) might be of interest to you.

Comment: Hi, I mean test cases with numbers. Files in txt or csv or json or some format with numbers that describe a real problem to be solved and that serves as a kind of benchmark. For example for subset sum, the file would include all numbers, the target sum, the result subset (if known), an indication if it is proved to be optimal (and perhaps some performance numbers from runs on various cpus and with various languages) ...

Comment: This depends entirely on the problem. Typically, there is no central repository for problem instances, but they are scattered here and there (for example, some are on the homepage of individual researchers, some might be somewhere on a research project homepage, etc.) What problem(s) are you interested in?

Answer (score 1):

If a paper experimentally compares algorithms, it should state the source of the test cases. Therefore a good way to find test cases would be to read the papers where practical algorithms for the particular problem are compared.

Some test case repositories that have been used in research papers (in graph algorithms):

- Dimacs graph coloring instances (these are frequently used for other graph problems too): https://mat.tepper.cmu.edu/COLOR/instances.html
- Bayesian networks: https://www.bnlearn.com/bnrepository/
- Treewidth instances: https://github.com/PACE-challenge/Treewidth
- Instances for minimum fill-in, steiner tree, hypertreewidth and vertex cover can also be found via PACE https://pacechallenge.org/
- Hypergraphs: http://hyperbench.dbai.tuwien.ac.at/
- Large network dataset collection: https://snap.stanford.edu/data/

Answer (score 0):

somehow I found the following

OR-Library at http://people.brunel.ac.uk/~mastjjb/jeb/info.html
(many datasets for many problems)

Bin Packing page at https://www2.wiwi.uni-jena.de/Entscheidung/binpp/index.htm
(datasets for bin packing)